# Localization Right to left

Tags: localization, arabic, right-to-left

In IOS 9 i can disable right to left language support with using below code

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .ForceLeftToRight
      } else {

        // Fallback on earlier versions
      }
```

but how can i disable in below IOS 9 version?